# How to set body to an http post request in c#

Tags: c#, http

A newbie to both c# and client-server, hope this is not dumb, but I was not able to understand how to set the body of an http post request.

I have to use the following object to make a request, and I can't understand how to set the request body to what I have to send.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestURI);
//
// Here I believe that I am suppose to set the post request body
//
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Thanks. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To set body you need to use `.PostAsync`. GET requests don't have body.

Comment: it's a post request though

Comment: Then why don't you use `.Post` method?

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
string xml = String.Empty;
// ... Fill in xml with your data
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("data", xml);

byte[] response = null;
string result = String.Empty;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    response = client.UploadValues(url, parameters);
    result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
}
```